# Environment properties not working in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a NodeJS app with Docker and Travis CI into AWS Elastic Beanstalk. My NodeJS app is dependent on `MONGO_URI` which I wish to pass as an environment variable. I tried adding it via the environmental properties but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Could you clarify what does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Do you get any error messages, timeouts, crashes, ...? Also how did you set the variable? Using `.ebextensions`?

Comment: No errors. Nope I didn't use .ebextensions. I passed it via the EBS dashboard where there is a key value provision for Environment Properties